# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined (using wysiwyg)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(".wysiwygtext").on("keyup keypress paste mouseup", function (e, t) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function (e, t) {
        var element = $(this).html(); //throws 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined'
        var value = $(this).val(); //throws 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined' error

        console.log(element);
        console.log(value);
    }, 2000);
});
```

`.wysiwyg` is a class applied to certain divs, like so (html is generated from the server):

```
<div class='wysiwygtext' data-guid='" + statementGuid + "' value='" + statementGuid + "'>" + lastbody + "</div>
```

I just need to retrieve the contents of the div (html) and the value (or ID) of the div upon any text change, but I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of
>   undefined

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com is more stable for this type of question, also put the line of code that's causing the error.

Comment: Where is `createDocumentFragment` in your provided code? How are we supposed to help you if you don't actually show what's causing the issue?

Comment: @vihan1086 sorry, I added more info.

Comment: @TimLewis Sorry, I added more info.

Comment: @vihan1086 Looks like the code is not working correctly. This would be closed as off-topic on Code Review until the code works as intended.

Comment: `$(this)` might not be what you think it is, since you're calling it inside your `setTimeout` function.

Comment: @TimLewis I also tried `t.$('.wysiwygtext')` but it threw an '$ is undefined' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this was a bunch of `undefined` references. This is how I ended up solving this:

```
var timeout = null;
$(".wysiwygtext").on("keyup keypress paste mouseup", function (e, t) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  var element = $(this).html();
  var value = $(this).val();
  timeout = setTimeout(function (e, t) {
    console.log(element);
    console.log(value);
  }, 2000);
});
```

I defined `timeout` outside the function, as `clearTimeout(timeout);` was throwing a `timeout is undefined` error. Next, I defined `element` and `value` outside of the timeout as `$(this).html()` and `$(this).val()` weren't referencing the right thing. Lastly, I kept `console.log(element)` and `colsole.log(value)` inside the timeout, so they will log 2 seconds after one of the above events.

Comment: Thanks! This has solved the errors. I am now faced with the issue as to why `console.log(value)` appears blank, but `console.log(element)` shows the appropriate text. Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: I can answer that too: `.val()` returns whatever is in the element's `value="..."` attribute. In the case of a `<div>`, `value="..."` won't be set, so it will return nothing.

Comment: But I have the value set in my code as `value='" + statementGuid + "'`, does the div just ignore that?

Comment: Two possibilities on that: `statementGuid` might not be set (or set to `" "`) **OR** since `value` isn't an attribute that can be applied to `<div>`'s, it might be ignored. You can always use `data-example='" + statementGuid + "'` and replace `$(this).val()` with `$(this).attr('data-example')` or `$(this).data('example)`.

Comment: Ah, used the latter option and it has sorted out. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I did some more reading and was gonna edit that comment to say the later is correct. `.val()` just can't be applied to `<div>`'s, as `value="..."` is invalid HTML. Glad you go it working though!